# Creating an array of images in python \ openCV \ numpy

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, opencv, numpy

I'm trying to implement an "LOG blob detector" using python and `openCV`.
the idea is to create 10-15 levels of LOG filters, apply each of them to my original gray scale image and save the images in an array of size `height` x `width` x `numOfLevels` and then find the local maximums on the 3D array.

The problem is I'm not sure how to save these in an array.

I tried to do the following:

```
myImage = cv2.imread('butterfly.jpg')
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(myImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
sigma = 2
k = 2**(0.25)
std2 = float(sigma**2)
arr = []
for i in range(10):
    filt_size =  2*np.ceil(3*sigma)+1
    H = log_filt( filt_size, sigma)
    H *= sigma**2
    dst = cv2.filter2D(gray_image,-1,H)
    arr.append(dst)
    cv2.imshow('Gray', dst)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    sigma = sigma * k
    std2 = float(sigma**2)
    plt.imshow(H,interpolation='nearest')
```

But then if I try to take on the of the images and use `cv2.imshow(arr[0])` I get the following error:

> `TypeError: Required argument 'mat' (pos 2) not found`

What am I doing wrong here?

Is there a better way to save these in an array?

Maybe using `np.array` somehow?

Comment: Please always include the full error traceback, not just the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error:

```
cv2.imshow(arr[0]) I get the following error: TypeError: Required argument 'mat' (pos 2) not found
```

Is because you pass the image (`arr[0]`) as first parameter, but you should pass it as second:

```
cv2.imshow('WindowName', arr[0])
```

See the OpenCV [2.4](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#imshow) and [3.0](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#imshow) documentation of `imshow`:

```
cv2.imshow(winname, mat)
```